# Can I use a cheap nRF51822 module from eBay to communicate with an iOS device to get notifications (ANCS)?

Tags: ios, arduino, ancs

Can I use a cheap nRF51822 board from eBay to get notifications from an iPhone with the Apple Notification Center Service (ANCS)? It also has an ARM mcu and built-in BLE. And is it possible to use it with the Arduino IDE, and if not, how to program it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use the nRF51822 with the ANCS.

https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/nrf51-ble-ancs-nus

It is possible to use it with the Arduino IDE, using this code from readbearlab
https://github.com/RedBearLab/nRF51822-Arduino

Nordic Semiconductor also have a developer zone where you can ask questions related to the nRF51 series and other nRF devices.
http://devzone.nordicsemi.com

BR